# Open .desktop files in text editor by default

Tags: desktop, mime-types

I wonder if it's possible to open files with the `.desktop` suffix in a text editor of choice by a simple double-click in a file manager. Even assigning the corresponding MIME type to a text editor with this command doesn't work:

```
xdg-mime default gedit.desktop application/x-desktop
```

I understand `.desktop` files are executables but is there a good reason it wouldn't be possible to do this?

Comment: Those are just text [configuration](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html) files by the way. So `text/plain` is closer to what you need than application/x-desktop I think.

Comment: @illuminÉ Hmm, when I go to properties of any `.desktop` file it says `Type: desktop configuration file (application/x-desktop)`

Comment: I see that too. I also see "ASCII text" when I use the `file` command on some .desktop file. I'm uncertain.

Comment: @illuminÉ Weird. `file --mime-type` actually does show `text/plain` for `.desktop` files.

Comment: I use Archbang (with OpenBox). I had never tried but if I double-click any of those .desktop file, they open in `medit` by default. You can query `xdg-mime query filetype path/to/your.desktopfile` - it gives me text/plain for any .desktop file. Indirect info about the topic [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal).

Comment: @illuminÉ Well, that's... interesting. It shows `application/x-desktop` for me.

Comment: Maybe try also `xdg-mime query default text/plain` and also with "application/x-desktop" instead of text plain - this last query echoes nothing for me. I suggest you please move the relevant parts of our exchange to your Q and specify your distribution.

Answer (score -1):

You can also define a `nautilus` script, so you can open the file in `gedit` using a right-click, regardless what file it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS ; do
    FILES="$f $FILES"
done

gedit $FILES &
```